# adding a Class Library project to a asp.net web-api project (REST service)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, sqlite, class-library

I am new on **C#** and I have a solution which consists of **two projects**: a **class library** project and a **REST** service project (asp-net web-api). Though both of them work when run independently (in the case of the Class Library by using an entry-point), when I add the **class library** project to the **REST** project as a reference and run it, it throws an exception. The exception states that it cannot find/load a library (**SQLite.Interop.dll**) which is actually referenced by my class library. Any ideas or hints is welcome !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SQLite.Interop.dll** is referred in Class lib project not in REST project.
Mark this **SQLite.Interop.dll** as copy local **true** in property.

[image]

Comment: **Hi Prashant**, thanks for your suggestion, but how do I mark it so...?

Comment: go to your class library then search for "SQLite.Interop.dll" right click "Properties" then search for property "Copy Local" as in screen shot then choose Option "true". Build your project again.